# Select data based on timestamp and interval from mysql

Tags: mysql

In joomla, it has jos_session table in which time is stored as unixtimestamp in 'time' column.
I want to select the records which are older then a week or two days, basically any interval.

Not much hands on DB, but i did tried with date_sub, but it seems taking date as an argument. So I also tried using FROM_UNIXTIME to convert, but nothing seems to be working.

The last query I tried was 
`SELECT username FROM jos_session WHERE DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'Y-m-d'), INTERVAL 2 DAY );`
But it seems to giving empty set and many warnings!

Can anyone please help!

Thanks in advance,
Tanmay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should work:

`SELECT 
  username 
FROM 
  jos_session 
WHERE 
TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(CAST(`time`AS UNSIGNED))) <  TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))-2`

Comment: Thanks Ashish. Thats seems to be working for me. Just one update on that, I had to use <= to get the records before two days.